# How to partition all dates by 7 days and do the grouping in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----------+
|    date    | day_of_week | item | num_order |
+------------+-------------+------+-----------+
| 2015-03-16 | Mon         | a    |        10 |
| 2015-03-16 | Mon         | a    |        10 |
| 2015-03-16 | Mon         | c    |        10 |
| 2015-03-15 | Sun         | b    |        10 |
| 2015-03-14 | Sat         | a    |        10 |
| 2015-03-13 | Fri         | c    |        10 |
| 2015-03-12 | Thu         | a    |        10 |
| 2015-03-11 | Wed         | b    |        10 |
| 2015-03-10 | Tue         | c    |        10 |
+------------+-------------+------+-----------+
```

What I need is

1. Group all rows by 7 days
2. Every 7 days starts from Wed
3. Aggregate sum on `num_order`

So basically, I want to see

> for every 7 days, starting from Wed always, what is the number of orders for each item

So in the end, I would like to see the table like this:

```
+------------+------+-----------------+
|  7_start   | item | total_num_order |
+------------+------+-----------------+
| 2015-03-11 | a    |              40 |
| 2015-03-11 | b    |              20 |
| 2015-03-11 | b    |              20 |
| 2015-03-04 | c    |              10 |
+------------+------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this? How can I partition the dates **by 7 days** and starting from **Wed** always?

Comment: Can you provide the table DDL and some insert statements? And make sure that he DATE values in the insert are not just strings, rather use TO_DATE with proper format mask in the INSERT statements. This is called a TEST CASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by week number. Since you want to start on a Wednesday, it's easier to base this on the ISO year and [week number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch9sql.htm#NLSPG448) (which always start on a Monday, with no NLS influence), and adjust by two days. You can see the adjusted week number for each date with:

```
select date_col, to_char(date_col - 2, 'IYYYIW') from <your_table>
```

You want to display the Wednesday date so you can adjust back two days the other way for display, and group by the (adjusted) year, week number and item:

```
select trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW') + 2, item, sum(num_order)
from <your table>
group by trunc(date_col - 2, 'IYYY'), trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW'), item
```

With your example data as a CTE:

```
with t (date_col, item, num_order) as (
  select date '2015-03-16', 'a', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-16', 'a', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-16', 'c', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-15', 'b', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-14', 'a', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-13', 'c', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-12', 'a', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-11', 'b', 10 from dual
  union all select date '2015-03-10', 'c', 10 from dual
)
select trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW') + 2 as period_start,
  item,
  sum(num_order) as total_num_order
from t
group by trunc(date_col - 2, 'IYYY'), trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW'), item
order by trunc(date_col - 2, 'IYYY'), trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW'), item;    

PERIOD_START ITEM TOTAL_NUM_ORDER
------------ ---- ---------------
04-MAR-15    c                 10
11-MAR-15    a                 40
11-MAR-15    b                 20
11-MAR-15    c                 20
```

You could use this instead for the same effect:

```
group by to_char(date_col - 2, 'IYYYIW'), trunc(date_col - 2, 'IW'), item
```

... but either way you need to group by both the year and week element if your data is going to span more than a year.